# Помогите обойти CORS в пользовательском скрипте

Tags: javascript

я не являюсь разработчиком, и не сильно разбираюсь в скриптах (по сути вообще не разбираюсь, делаю методом тыка). Так вот я пытаюсь сделать себе пользовательский скрипт для одного сайта (который будет выполняться только  у меня в браузере и больше нигде), и застрял на этапе с ошибкой CORS, она меня добивает и я не знаю как с ней бороться, скажите что я могу дописать в код чтобы эта ошибка исчезла?

Вот скрипт

```
fetch(`https://www.google.com/search?q=test`)
.then(response => response.text())
```

Кто-то может решить эту проблему без использования прокси, и сторонних расширений для браузера? Пожалуйста помогите, я уже весь гугл перешарил, но подходящего мне решения не могу найти =(

Comment: `fetch('https://www.google.com/search?q=test', {mode: 'no-cors'})`

Comment: Добавил {mode: 'no-cors'} но теперь у меня пустой ответ походу просто